# Getline is ignored at random times in a do while loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

So, what I am trying to achieve is calling the commands that are in my void (named Command) containing commands for this program. I would normally call them like this: `Command("kill me")` as its first and only parameter is an `std::string`, but I want to call them in a simple console. It works the first time I do it, but then it doesn't work, and sometimes ignores my `cout` I put in the loop. Here is my code:

```
void Command(std::string cmd) {
    //commands here
}

std::string CmdInput(std::string cmd) {
    std::getline(std::cin, cmd);
    Command(cmd);
    return cmd;
}

do {
    //this is in main
    std::string cmd;
    std::cout("-> ");
    std::getline(std::cin, cmd);
    CmdInput(cmd);
} while (true);
```

Here is a gif of what happens when I try to use it:
[image: Image Link]

I just don't see what is wrong with my loop.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [discussing every line of your program, step by step, with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two getline functions, once in your main and the other in your CmdInput. So I guess its waiting for your second input